# HTML Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

I have a table alignment I’m having trouble doing what I want it to do. Below is what I have, but I want the cell with 1 in it to hug the top the whole table while I want the cell with 2 in it to hug the bottom baseline of the table. Cell 3 may have variable height. Anyone know how this possible? Probably something simple I’m missing but having figured it out yet.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr>
       <td valign="top">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="50">
              <tr>
                     <td>1
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td height="200" width="50">3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `height="100%"` on your tables, along with some `valign` attributes on the cells.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%">
  <tr>
  <td>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="50" height="100%">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <table><tr><td height="200" width="50">3</td></tr></table>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah figured it out:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="300" height="19">1</td>
    <td width="300" rowspan="2">
    <br>
    <br>
    3<br>
    <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom">
    <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using br tags for alignment.